# iOS 7 - Change bar button size

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Is there any legitimate way to change the size of a bar button in iOS 7 (i.e. the font size of the text)? I find the default bar button size a bit too big comparing to the navigation bar title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `setTitleTextAttributes:forState:` method on the `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10] };
[barButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:attrs forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Obviously you can choose whatever font you want.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the bar button item with a custom view:

```
BarButtonItem *myBarButton = [[BarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myCustomView];
```

The custom view is any UIView.

Answer (score 1):

In swift:

```
    var attrs:NSDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)]
    barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes(attrs, forState: .Normal)
```